# Unable to install likewise-open in Raspberry Pi

Tags: apt, ubuntu

I've tried to install likewise-open in my Raspberry Pi. Before that, I've edited my repository list, where /etc/apt/sources.list is as follows:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free r$
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu maverick-security main restricted universe
```

But it returned the following message:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo apt-get install likewise-open
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package likewise-open
```

1. In general, how can I know if a package is not available?
2. Is likewise-open not supported in Raspberry Pi? I'm able to install it in Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 4):

> Is likewise-open not supported in Raspberry Pi? I'm able to install it in Ubuntu 10.10

Don't bother looking for software beyond the raspbian repos.  Binary software must be compiled for a specific architecture (processor), which is why there are, e.g., x86-64 packages and i386 packages, etc.

The pi has an unusual processor, and this is whole reason raspbian and the other pi distros exist.  They've been compiled for that architecture, and software compiled for a different architecture simply will not work.

Software that isn't available pre-compiled can be built from source on the pi, but I fear that "likewise-open", which currently is called [something else](http://download1.beyondtrust.com/Technical-Support/Downloads/PowerBroker-Identity-Services-Open-Edition/?Pass=True), doesn't distribute source packages from their download site. The "open" in "open edition" implies the source might be available if you dig around (although beware this doesn't guarantee it will compile on the pi).

There is also a good chance that the reason it wasn't ported into raspbian is because it's a genuinely non-free package for which no source is available.